# Why doesn't my registration mutation work with the role field?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto, absinthe

Why doesn't my registration mutation work with the role field?

I written the following code but can't figure out why my role enum doesn't work with my mutation.

I uploaded my code to github [Github code](https://github.com/wolfiton/phx_api/tree/role_not_working).

**The registration mutation works**:

```
mutation{
      registerUser(input:{email:"a@a.com", password:"a@a.com", role:"user",passwordConfirmation:"a@a.com"}){
        email

      }
    }
```

**But when i try my login mutation it fails**:

```
mutation{
  loginUser(input:{email:"a@a.com", password:"a@a.com", role:"user"}){
    token
    user{
      email
    }
  }
}
```

**And I get this error:**:

```
"# KeyError at POST /api/graphiql\n\nException:\n\n    
** (KeyError) key :role not found in: %{email: \"a@a.com\", password: \"a@a.com\"}\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what i was doing wrong was answered for me on the elixirforum by @benwilson512.

The following assumption of mine that I can use `field(:role, :user_input)` to get the input type form my user_input was incorrect.

If I want to pass down the role to my mutation the best way is to use `field(:role, non_null(:string))` and treated as a string.

But still i am not sure what is the best way to deal with this, although this solves the problem I was having.

So thanks everyone that looked over my question.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to restrict the role to the enum values then the following should work:

`field(:role, :type :role)` and then the enum for the role with the values.

This answer was offered by @kokolegorille on elixirforum.

That solves the problem